# Unable to connect redis sentinel using jedis

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I am trying to connect to redis sentinel using JedisSentinelPool

```
private static final JedisSentinelPool pool = new JedisSentinelPool("mymaster", getSentinels());

private static Set<String> getSentinels(){

    Set<String> mysentinels = new HashSet<>();
    mysentinels.add(new HostAndPort("localhost", 26379).toString());
    return mysentinels;
}
```

This gives me following error :

> Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels down, cannot determine where is mymaster master is running...

However, I can see that my sentinel is running. So referring to this post:
https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/64
 I tried the below command on my redis master server

```
./redis-cli -h redis-1 -p 26379
```

I got following error:

> Could not connect to Redis at redis-1:26379: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

What is the issue here?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Provided the sentinel path and I've checked from the `redis-cli` that my sentinel is running. Still I am getting the same exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 works for me.

> By default Sentinel will not be reachable from interfaces different than
>   localhost, either use the 'bind' directive to bind to a list of network
>   interfaces, or disable protected mode with "protected-mode no" by
>   adding it to this configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `protected-mode` is set to `no` in `sentinel.conf` file. This solved issue for me.